# SQL - Double pivot - Second pivot (With Count) not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a table like the following. Let's call it `TBL1`:

```
                    SINIF                                        NAME_  CURCODE    TARIH       TARIHS     TAKSIT
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2015    2015 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2016    2016 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2016    2016 SAYI   28770,13
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD     2016    2016 SAYI   28732,89
     02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ         TEB KREDİ - 100.000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ)      EUR     2015    2015 SAYI    2024,67
     02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ         TEB KREDİ - 100.000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ)      EUR     2015    2015 SAYI    2024,67
     02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ         TEB KREDİ - 100.000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ)      EUR     2015    2015 SAYI    2024,67
```

Note that `TARIHS` is just version of `TARIH` with a string `SAYI` added at the end. I use it because I need different column names for a double pivot. I want to construct a double pivot that does the following:

```
SUM(TAKSIT) vs TARIH (2015, 2016, 2017)
COUNT(TARIHS) vs TARIHS (2015 SAYI, 2016 SAYI, 2017 SAYI)
```

Hence, I would like to get a table like the following:

```
                    SINIF                                        NAME_  CURCODE        2015      2016    2017    2015 SAYI    2016 SAYI    2017 SAYI
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD    345243.6   86310.9    NULL           12            3         NULL
     02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ         TEB KREDİ - 100.000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ)      EUR     6074.01      NULL    NULL            3         NULL         NULL
```

However, when I construct the double pivot, I get the following:

```
                    SINIF                                        NAME_  CURCODE        2015      2016    2017    2015 SAYI    2016 SAYI    2017 SAYI
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD    345243.6      NULL    NULL            1            0            0
01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ   VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1.500.000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)      USD        NULL   86310.9    NULL            0            1            0
     02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ         TEB KREDİ - 100.000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ)      EUR     6074.01      NULL    NULL            1            0            0
```

Can someone help me with my code? I did not paste my original code here because it is a bit long, but I summarized it for you to get a general idea.

I also would like to let you know that my code works if I remove `TARIHS` from all the selections and just want to do the first pivot. However, When I add the second pivot with `TARIHS` into the mix, I get a table that is not what I want.

THANKS!

Comment: Could you provide a SQL Fiddle example?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what that is

Comment: @king.code - Added fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71d67/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be you are selecting the all the column `SINIF, NAME_ , CURCODE, TARIH, TARIHS, TAKSIT` in pivot source query. Try changing your query like this.

in the source pivot query

```
SELECT a.SINIF,a.NAME_,a.CURCODE,
       [2015],[2016],[2017],
       [2015 SAYI],[2016 SAYI],[2017 SAYI]
FROM  (SELECT *
       FROM   (SELECT SINIF,NAME_,CURCODE,TAKSIT,tarih
               FROM   Tablename) a
              PIVOT (Sum(TAKSIT)
                    FOR tarih IN([2015],[2016],[2017]))piv) a
      JOIN(SELECT *
           FROM   (SELECT SINIF,NAME_,CURCODE,TARIHS
                   FROM   Tablename) a
                  PIVOT (Count(TARIHS)
                        FOR TARIHS IN([2015 SAYI],[2016 SAYI],[2017 SAYI]))piv) b
        ON a.SINIF = b.SINIF
           AND a.NAME_ = b.NAME_
           AND a.CURCODE = b.CURCODE
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71d67/1)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62619/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table(SINIF NVARCHAR(1000), NAME NVARCHAR(200)
, CURCODE NVARCHAR(1000) , TARIH INT, TARIHS VARCHAR(100), TAKSIT DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2015,'2015 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2016,'2016 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2016,'2016 SAYI',   28770.13),
(N'01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ', N'VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ)','USD', 2016,'2016 SAYI',   28732.89),
  (N'02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ',         N'TEB KREDİ - 100000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ)','EUR', 2015,'2015 SAYI',    2024.67),
  (N'02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ',         N'TEB KREDİ - 100000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ)','EUR', 2015,'2015 SAYI',    2024.67),
  (N'02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ',         N'TEB KREDİ - 100000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ)','EUR', 2015,'2015 SAYI',    2024.67)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT SINIF ,NAME ,CURCODE , CAST(TARIH AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Years, TAKSIT  
 FROM Test_Table 
UNION ALL
SELECT SINIF , NAME , CURCODE, TARIHS , COUNT(*) counts FROM Test_Table
GROUP BY SINIF , NAME , CURCODE , TARIHS ) t 
  PIVOT (SUM(TAKSIT)
         FOR Years
         IN ([2015],[2016],[2017],[2015 SAYI],[2016 SAYI],[2017 SAYI])) P
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62619/2/0)**:

```
|                     SINIF |                                     NAME | CURCODE |      2015 |     2016 |   2017 | 2015 SAYI | 2016 SAYI | 2017 SAYI |
|---------------------------|------------------------------------------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 01 - TİCARİ (GENEL) KREDİ | VAKIFBANK KREDİ - 1500000 USD (TÜKETİCİ) |     USD | 345241.56 | 86273.15 | (null) |        12 |         3 |    (null) |
|      02 - YATIRIM KREDİSİ |      TEB KREDİ - 100000 EUR (ARAÇ KREDİ) |     EUR |   6074.01 |   (null) | (null) |         3 |    (null) |    (null) |
```